# How am I receiving emails addressed to an address not associated with my account?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

I currently have a g-mail address (example@gmail.com).  I recently received a message addressed to example@aol.com. Looking at the header I see my correct address in the Delivered-To: field but in the To: and cc: fields it's showing the example@aol.com.  How is this message getting to my g-mail account?

Comment: Note that there are two places where recipient email addresses are specified when sending an email.  1) the RCPT TO address (which is part of the SMTP protocol), and 2) the To: field in the message header.  In your case, it sounds like example@gmail.com may have been specified as the SMTP RCPT TO address, and example@aol.com may have been specified in the To: field in the message header.  This is exactly what would have happened if the sender sent the message to example@aol.com, and specified example@gmail.com in the bcc field.

Comment: What about the reply-to field? Isn't that also an option? Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SirMuffington – When you reply to a message, your email client looks for a `Reply-To` header and uses its listed recipient(s) instead of the `From` header, but that goes into the `To` header of your new message. The correct answer to this question is @​mti2935's comment about SMTP `rcpt to` commands (which is how Bcc is implemented).